# Vaadin Grid Table : How to disable Sort Function and set the color of one column

Tags: java, sorting, colors, vaadin

I'm using `Grid` table in Vaadin for data representation. 
For that I'm trying to figure out the following two issues:

1.) How to disable the sort function in the Header of each column

2.) How to set the color of one column in a `Grid` table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I find the [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) a good place to start looking for help. For the rest of the exercise, suppose we have a `Grid` with 3 simple columns c1, c2 & c3:

```java
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.addColumn("c1", String.class);
grid.addColumn("c2", String.class);
grid.addColumn("c3", String.class);
```

> 1.) How to disable the sort function in the Header of each column

Iterate through each column and set its sortable property to *false*:

```java
for (Grid.Column column : grid.getColumns()) {
    column.setSortable(false);
}
```

Or just get that one column you want and set its sortable property:

```java
grid.getColumn("c1").setSortable(false);
```

> 2.) How to set the color of one column in a Grid table

Similar to how it [was done with the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554463/vaadin-coloring-table-cells-based-on-content), you need to define your CSS style in your [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html):

```css
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;
  // Insert your own theme rules here

  .v-grid-cell.green {
    background: #33BB00;
  }
}
```

And use a [CellStyleGenerator](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.stylegeneration.cell) to apply the style to your desired column:

```java
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(new Grid.CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Grid.CellReference cellReference) {
        if ("c1".equals(cellReference.getPropertyId())) {
            return "green";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Which should generate something along the lines of:

[image]

Comment: This approach doesn't work anymore, as the method `setCellStyleGenerator()` has been removed on the Grid class. Instead, I presume the following could be used, bu I haven't verified this, yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464437/how-to-color-a-row-or-cell-of-a-grid-depending-on-its-data-in-vaadin-14

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small supplement to [Morfic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474287/morfic) good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607023/4408171):

> 1.) How to disable the sort function in the Header of each column

Grid asks the Container if a column is sortable (see appendColumn-method in Grid). If you want to disable sorting for all columns, you can override getSortableContainerPropertyIds in your Container and return an empty collection:

```
container = new BeanContainer<String, Dive>(Dive.class) {
            @Override
            public Collection<?> getSortableContainerPropertyIds() {
                LinkedList<Object> sortables = new LinkedList<Object>();
                return sortables;
            }
        };
```