# Vaadin Grid Table: how to draw border for certain columns?

Tags: java, css, grid, vaadin

I'm using Vaadins Grid table for data representation.
Therefore I want to draw a thick line for the right border of the `Employee`-ID-column and for both border sides of the `name` or  `name` and `surname` column.

The result should look like this:

[image]

How I can manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where we left off in your [other question regarding cell background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602385/vaadin-grid-table-how-to-disable-sort-function-and-set-the-color-of-one-column), update your [`CellStyleGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.stylegeneration.cell) to handle your other columns. For the sake of brevity I'll just demo a column with both borders, but you'll get the idea:

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(new Grid.CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Grid.CellReference cellReference) {
        if ("c1".equals(cellReference.getPropertyId())) {
            return "green";
        } else if ("c2".equals(cellReference.getPropertyId())) {
            return "right-and-left-border";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

... add the appropriate styles in your [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) file:

```css
.v-grid-cell.right-and-left-border {
  border-left: solid 2px black;
  border-right: solid 2px black;
}
```

... and you should get something similar to:

[image: sample]

Comment: how i can call this change, because i add your .v-grid-cel ... rule to styles.scss and then call your method to setstylegenerator, but i can't see any changes in my theme after refresh and recompile. When i try add your css code only to grid-cell, i see the border in every cell. But i want have border in the specific columns too...

Comment: @Ady96 Please consider creating a new question with all the details regarding your app (code, theme, etc), so we can better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Add style name to your grid component:

   ```
   Grid grid = new Grid();
   grid.addStyleName("grid-column-seperators")
   ```
2. Then in your *.scss file you need to add css style for class `.grid-column-separator` that add thick lines in your grid as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313456/css-borders-between-table-columns-only)

Remember to compile Vaadin theme before deploying your app to see desired effect.