# Set border to the grid (Vaadin 7.4.9)

Tags: grid, vaadin

I need to add border to the columns in grid.

[image]

In my webapp I have addons.scss, mytheme.scss, styles.scss and styles.css. How i can add this new borders into my grid?

My grid code -

@Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
container.addContainerProperty("September", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person1", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person2", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person3", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person4", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person5", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person6", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person7", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("Person8", Integer.class, 0);

Grid.HeaderRow row = grid.addHeaderRowAt(0);
Grid.HeaderRow row2 = grid.addHeaderRowAt(1);

String[] Group1 = {"Person3", "Person4", "Person1", "Person2"};
String[] Group2 = {"Person7", "Person8", "Person5", "Person6"};      
String[] Group3 = {"Person3", "Person4"};    
String[] Group4 = {"Person1", "Person2"};    
String[] Group5 = {"Person7", "Person8"};    
String[] Group6 = {"Person5", "Person6"};    

row.join(Group1).setText("Čerpacia stanica");
row.join(Group2).setText("Panos");

row2.join(Group3).setText("TPP");
row2.join(Group4).setText("Brigada");
row2.join(Group5).setText("TPP");
row2.join(Group6).setText("Brigada");

container.addItem(1);

Item item = container.getItem(1);
item.getItemProperty("September").setValue("1.9.2017 Piatok");
...


 //This is from your post
 grid.setCellStyleGenerator(new Grid.CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Grid.CellReference cellReference) {
       if ("TPP".equals(cellReference.getPropertyId()) || 
           "Brigáda".equals(cellReference.getPropertyId())) {
            return "right-and-left-border";
       else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
}
```

There is class that i have in my webapp folder.

Mytheme.scss

```
// If you edit this file you need to compile the theme. See README.md for details.

// Global variable overrides. Must be declared before importing Valo.

// Defines the plaintext font size, weight and family. Font size affects general component sizing.
//$v-font-size: 16px;
//$v-font-weight: 300;
//$v-font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;

// Defines the border used by all components.
//$v-border: 1px solid (v-shade 0.7);
//$v-border-radius: 4px;

// Affects the color of some component elements, e.g Button, Panel title, etc
//$v-background-color: hsl(210, 0%, 98%);
// Affects the color of content areas, e.g  Panel and Window content, TextField input etc
//$v-app-background-color: $v-background-color;

// Affects the visual appearance of all components
//$v-gradient: v-linear 8%;
//$v-bevel-depth: 30%;
//$v-shadow-opacity: 5%;

// Defines colors for indicating status (focus, success, failure)
//$v-focus-color: valo-focus-color(); // Calculates a suitable color automatically
//$v-friendly-color: #2c9720;
//$v-error-indicator-color: #ed473b;

// For more information, see: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.valo.html
// Example variants can be copy/pasted from https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Valo+Examples

@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {

  @include valo;

.mytheme .v-grid-cell
{

    font-size: 5px;
    overflow: visible;

}

 //I insert this code here
.v-grid-cell.right-and-left-border {
 border-left: solid 2px black;
 border-right: solid 2px black;
 }

  // Insert your own theme rules here
}
```

There is code from styles.scss

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";

// This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes.
// The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss

.mytheme {

  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;

}
```

This is class addons.scss

```
/* This file is automatically managed and will be overwritten from time to time. */
/* Do not manually edit this file. */

/* Import and include this mixin into your project theme to include the addon themes */
@mixin addons {
}
```

And styles.css have 13000 lines ...

After insert your code into mytheme.scss and grid set style method into my java code, then i recompiled the project. But when i refresh the page, all is the same.

--
Now I want update some styles in my theme. E.G

```
.mytheme .v-grid-row > td, .mytheme .v-grid-editor-cells > div {

    font-size: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

and i want have some new styles

```
.mytheme .v-grid-row > td, .mytheme .v-grid-editor-cells > div {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

Where do I save it? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Shirkam You're pretty close to the truth. That's the question from which this one originates. He added [a comment to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677935/vaadin-grid-table-how-to-draw-border-for-certain-columns/35702156?noredirect=1#comment79374035_35702156) about not being able to use it in his application, as in nothing changed visually after he had modified the sources as per that answer. So I suggested to open a new question providing all the details relevant to his case (code, theme, etc). Unfortunately, these details are missing...

Comment: Oh, that's fine then, so please @Ady96 post your sources so we can help you.

Comment: What type of source you want ? .css or scss ? Or ?

Comment: Scss is fine (the css is generated from it but it's too big anyway). But I don't see where in your theme you're defining your custom styles, nor where they're applied from the grind style generators. Please show us exactly what you did, and describe the problems you encountered.

Comment: Check my edited post now ... in myscss is new code, and in init too ...

Comment: Have you debugged your code?
Does it enter your if in `getStyle`? Maybe the error is using column agrupations instead of single columns...

Comment: @Shirkam is right. It's definitely an issue in your `if` as `TPP` & `Brigada` are not propertyIds, they're just captions. I looked through the Vaadin sources some time ago, so I don't fully remember how it's done, but the ids of grouped columns are something composed from the participating columns, and I'm not sure they're accessible (I'll take a look when I have the time). Try using the actual Ids that you defined, such as `Person1`, `Person2`, etc. Also where did you find Vaadin `v7.4.9`, is that a typo of `7.7.9`?

Comment: Morfic and Shirkam - > thank you very much ! It is great ! :) And you are great too :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you managed to fix your problem, please consider taking some time to post your solution so others with similar issues can also benefit from it.

Comment: @Morfic can you read my edited post again ? Thanks :)

Comment: Your custom styles should go in `mytheme.scss`, inside the `@mixin mytheme { ... }` section, and without the `.mytheme` _prefix_. You can find more details about Vaadin themes [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) (please be aware that there are multiple chapters in the left-side menu)

Comment: @Morfic have you answer for this problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078096/using-vaadin-7-4-9-how-to-delete-data-from-the-grid/46097276?noredirect=1#comment79393337_46097276